# Count occurrences of each key in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a python dictionary object that looks somewhat like this:

```
[{"house": 4,  "sign": "Aquarius"},
 {"house": 2,  "sign": "Sagittarius"},
 {"house": 8,  "sign": "Gemini"},
 {"house": 3,  "sign": "Capricorn"},
 {"house": 2,  "sign": "Sagittarius"},
 {"house": 3,  "sign": "Capricorn"},
 {"house": 10, "sign": "Leo"},
 {"house": 4,  "sign": "Aquarius"},
 {"house": 10, "sign": "Leo"},
 {"house": 1,  "sign": "Scorpio"}]
```

Now for each 'sign' key, I'd like to count how many times each value occurs.

```
def predominant_sign(data):
    signs = [k['sign'] for k in data if k.get('sign')]
    print len(signs)
```

This however, prints number of times 'sign' appears in the dictionary, instead of getting the value of the `sign` and counting the number of times a particular value appears.

For example, the output I'd like to see is:

```
Aquarius: 2
Sagittarius: 2
Gemini: 1
...
```

And so on. What should I change to get the desired output?

Comment: You want the result to be in any particular order?

Comment: @thefourtheye, Not really. Any order is fine. The two answers below did the trick in no time. :)

Comment: Also, you have a list of Python dictionaries :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its [`most_common` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
from collections import Counter
def predominant_sign(data):
    signs = Counter(k['sign'] for k in data if k.get('sign'))
    for sign, count in signs.most_common():
        print(sign, count)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module, with a simple generator expression, like this

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(k['sign'] for k in data if k.get('sign'))
Counter({'Sagittarius': 2, 'Capricorn': 2, 'Aquarius': 2, 'Leo': 2, 'Scorpio': 1, 'Gemini': 1})
```

This will give you a dictionary which has the `signs` as keys and their number of occurrences as the values.

---

You can do the same with a normal dictionary, like this

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for k in data:
...     if 'sign' in k:
...         result[k['sign']] = result.get(k['sign'], 0) + 1
>>> result
{'Sagittarius': 2, 'Capricorn': 2, 'Aquarius': 2, 'Leo': 2, 'Scorpio': 1, 'Gemini': 1}
```

The `dictionary.get` method, accepts a second parameter, which will be the default value to be returned if the key is not found in the dictionary. So, if the current sign is not in `result`, it will give `0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
def counter(my_list):
    my_list = sorted(my_list)
    first_val, *all_val = my_list
    p_index = my_list.index(first_val)
    my_counter = {}
    for item in all_val:
         c_index = my_list.index(item)
         diff = abs(c_index-p_index)
         p_index = c_index
         my_counter[first_val] = diff 
         first_val = item
    c_index = my_list.index(item)
    diff = len(my_list) - c_index
    my_counter[first_val] = diff 
    return my_counter

>>> counter([list(i.values())[1] for i in my_list])
{'Aquarius': 2,
 'Capricorn': 2,
 'Gemini': 1,
 'Leo': 2,
 'Sagittarius': 2,
 'Scorpio': 1}
```