# How to count a value with JSON based on another value in the JSON file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file made up of an array which contains dictionaries, each dictionary is  an opinion of a buyer on a specific garage.
I want to find out how many occurrence of each car's type I have in each garage, it looks like this:

```
[
  {"garage": "mike_gar", "reliability": 6, "car_type": "ford", "time": "16:10:36"},
  {"garage": "bill_gar", "reliability": 5,"car_type": "kia", "time": "4:37:22"},
  {"garage": "alison_gar", "reliability": 1, "car_type": "kia", "time": "11:25:40"},
  {"garage": "alison_gar", "reliability": 10, "car_type": "mazda", "time": "2:18:42"},
  {"garage": "mike_gar", "reliability": 3, "car_type": "mazda", "time": "12:14:20"},
  {"garage": "mike_gar", "reliability": 2, "car_type": "ford", "time": "2:08:27"}
]
```

Assuming we already read from the JSON file to a variable g_arr.
I'v tried to use reduce() to count the occurrence , but failed to succeed.

**output example:** `{"garage" : "mike_gar", "types":{"ford" : 2, "mazda": 1}}`

Comment: Is Jason the guy who owns the garage?

Comment: @wim I think it's supposed to be JSON. Fixed that.

Comment: @wim opppsss...

Comment: @Shelly875 I think you will find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963408/count-occurrences-of-each-key-in-python-dictionary) helpful. Let us know if that solves your problem. It isn't an exact duplicate, but it is pretty closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on reduction. First, I test whether the garage exists in the accumulation dictionary, and if not, create it. Then, I check whether the car type exists in the garage dictionary, and if not, I create it. Finally, I increment the car type.

```
res = {}

for d in garages:
    if d["garage"] not in res:
        res[d["garage"]] = {"garage": d["garage"], "types": {}}

    if d["car_type"] not in res[d["garage"]]["types"]:
        res[d["garage"]]["types"][d["car_type"]] = 0

    res[d["garage"]]["types"][d["car_type"]] += 1
```

Output:

```
{
  'mike_gar': {'garage': 'mike_gar', 'types': {'ford': 2, 'mazda': 1}},
  'bill_gar': {'garage': 'bill_gar', 'types': {'kia': 1}}, 
  'alison_gar': {'garage': 'alison_gar', 'types': {'kia': 1, 'mazda': 1}}
}
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/VoluminousCarelessAnalyst)

If you'd like your result in an array, use `res.values()`.

Comment: That is a Javascript solution, the question has a Python tag.

Comment: I'v tried the code and that's exactly what I was looking for! thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply parse your data and do the count as the following:

```
garages = []
cars = []
output = []

for element in data:
    if element['garage'] not in garages: garages.append(element['garage'])
    if element['car_type'] not in cars: cars.append(element['car_type'])

for type in garages:
    current = {}
    current['types'] = {}
    current['garage'] = type
    for element in data:
        if element['car_type'] not in current['types']:
            current['types'][element['car_type']]=0

        if current['garage'] == element['garage']:
            for car_type in cars:
                if element['car_type'] == car_type:
                    current['types'][element['car_type']]+=1
    output.append(current)

print output
```

the output of executing the above is:

```
[{'garage': 'mike_gar', 'types': {'mazda': 1, 'kia': 0, 'ford': 2}}, {'garage': 'bill_gar', 'types': {'mazda': 0, 'kia': 1, 'ford': 0}}, {'garage': 'alison_gar', 'types': {'mazda': 1, 'kia': 1, 'ford': 0}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas package is great for working with a such data. You can easily convert your list into a Pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(g_arr)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  car_type      garage  reliability      time
0     ford    mike_gar            6  16:10:36
1      kia    bill_gar            5   4:37:22
2      kia  alison_gar            1  11:25:40
3    mazda  alison_gar           10   2:18:42
4    mazda    mike_gar            3  12:14:20
5     ford    mike_gar            2   2:08:27
```

Than you can use the `.groupby()` method to group your data and the `.size()` method to get row counts per group.

```
print(df.groupby(['garage', 'car_type']).size())
```

Prints:

```
garage      car_type
alison_gar  kia         1
            mazda       1
bill_gar    kia         1
mike_gar    ford        2
            mazda       1
dtype: int64
```